# What is insecure about generating a random number with keccak256?

Tags: ethereum-wallet-dapp, keccak

Just read that generating random a random number via `keccak256` is insecure. What is insecure about it and what are the implications of insecurity?

Comment: Via `keccak256` of what? Calling a hash function on a value doesn't change the randomness of the underlying value.

Comment: This link help https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/34988/honest-lottery-winner-generation-pseudo-random-number-obtaining

Answer (score 2):

It's not the keccak, which is btw. just an hashing algorithm, but more the input you give to that, that can be cheated on. For example if you would try to make randomness with the block number, the miners could hack it. If you hash the block number with keccak, this would not change the fact that it's manipulable.

Answer (score 0):

The number will always be the same, the difference between the numbers `1` and `2` will be massive when ran through a Keccak hash, however, they will always be the same each time they are hashed.