# How to get current time by solidity?

Tags: solidity, timestamp

I'd like to describe time like `Apr15th 10:00AM` . I know how to describe time range as follows, but I am not sure how to call date of time. Could you tell me about it if you know?

```
1 == 1 second
1 minutes == 60 seconds
1 hours == 60 minutes
1 days == 24 hours
1 weeks = 7 days
1 years = 365 days
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

15 April 2016 10:00 UTC translates to 1460714400 in Unix Timestamp.

I never used it but there is this library by @pipermerriam called [ethereum-datetime](https://github.com/pipermerriam/ethereum-datetime), so you could call his contract to get what you want

Comment: Note that the *ethereum-datetime* does not provide the smart contract with the current datetime. *ethereum-date* provides you with the ability to format the time instead of displaying the number of seconds since 01/01/1970.

Comment: @BokkyPooBah I assume this means there is no way of getting current time in solidity (yet) ?

Comment: @TeleportingGoat In your solidity contract code you are able to access the block.timestamp - see http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/413/can-a-contract-safely-rely-on-block-timestamp/428#428

Comment: Is this library workable for polygon as well???

Answer (score 20):

I believe what you're looking for is `block.timestamp`:

```
chainStartTime = block.timestamp;
```

Previously, there was `now`, but it has been deprecated

Comment: "now" has been deprecated. Use "block.timestamp" instead.

Comment: There are several workarounds. The first one is based on the block's timestamp: each timestamp should be bigger than the parent's one, although nodes can manipulate timestamp especially when it promises profits to them, also blocks could be rejected during mining. The second one is based on using the block’s number as they are ordered one-by-one and by knowing average block time execution calculate current time - unfortunately the time of block mining also might vary, especially with new ethereum updates. Seems like the timestamp of the block is the better option.

Answer (score 2):

block.timestamp does not give the current time, as you might expect a clock on the wall to.  In a mined block, block.timestamp is the local time of the miner's machine when the block was mined. For live transactions running in a yet to be mined block, the block.timestamp is the timestamp of the most recently mined block. It will be reset to the time of the miner's local clock when that block gets mined.  To get a live time feed you have to go to an external source.