# SmartContract determine timestamp of saving data

Tags: solidity, nethereum

I have really simple solidity smartcontract for saving and fetching data structs.
When I ask for data struct (fetching function) I need to know timestamp (or block ID) when was the struct saved. How to accomplish that?

Saving timestamp as part of struct data seems really stupid to me...

PS: I am developing in C# and Nethereum

Thanks

Comment: Maybe "block.timestamp" would be sollution: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/413/can-a-contract-safely-rely-on-block-timestamp/

Comment: Another option could be to use events to log the timestamp when the data was added to the blockchain.