# Random number inside contract

Tags: contract-design

It is possible to generate truly (not pseudo) random number with specific range inside smart contacts

(for example I need random number between 1 and 60 000 )

Thx!

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to do so. Suppose there exists a way to generate a truly random number in a contract, then two nodes/ miners will generate two different values, thus end up having two different blockchain states. No consensus can be achieved in such scenario.

Comment: There are some ways [#1](http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/191/259), [#2](https://www.reddit.com/r/ethereum/comments/442z66/how_to_generate_a_number_between_110_in_solidity/?), [#3](https://gist.github.com/alexvandesande/259b4ffb581493ec0a1c)

Comment: @NikhilM op was asking about generating totally random numbers. Any solutions in your references can be easily biased.

Comment: I understand that, i just wanted to show you some possible ways since the question was already discussed in SE.