# How can I split certain part of a number variable?

Tags: solidity

In a smart contract using Solidity, how can I split certain characters of a number variable?

I specifically need to take last two symbols of a hexadecimal number.

Comment: utf8 encoded?  Where's the encoded data coming from?  A code snippet would be useful here for context.

If you are trying to decode a utf8 encoded string there should be plenty of algorithms you can google for that could be ported to solidity.

Comment: I have block hash e.g. 0x1ceeb282f22d09352d03c2e9a5e43b4a63fafbeb1424622fef8e390df493030e and I wan't to take last 2 character from that hash, i.e. 0e to be used as a pseudorandom number for game.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use the bitwise operator '&' to extract the parts of the numbers. Example:

```
function getTest1() constant returns (uint256) {
  uint256 number = 0x1ceeb282f22d09352d03c2e9a5e43b4a63fafbeb1424622fef8e390df493030e;
  return number & 0xff;
}
```

or if you want the number in a 16 bit unsigned integer:

```
function getTest2() constant returns (uint16) {
  uint256 number = 0x1ceeb282f22d09352d03c2e9a5e43b4a63fafbeb1424622fef8e390df493030e;
  return uint16(number & 0xff);
}
```

The results look like:

```
> test.getTest1()
14
> test.getTest2()
14
```

Some other references you may be interested in:

- [How can I securely generate a random number in my smart contract?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/191/how-can-i-securely-generate-a-random-number-in-my-smart-contract)
- https://gist.github.com/alexvandesande/259b4ffb581493ec0a1c