# does the smart contract have something similar to the locktime in bitcoin?

Tags: contract-design

I want to develop a multi step gambling game with the contract, does the smart contract have something similar to the locktime in bitcoin to make the transactions can not be processed before certain time point

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write the rules in the smart contract to only calculate the multi-step payouts when the block number (accessed through the global variable block.number as documented in [do the contracts of ethereum have the access to the nonce of the blocks?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/2701/do-the-contracts-of-ethereum-have-the-access-to-the-nonce-of-the-blocks)) exceeds your preset payout block numbers.

E.g. Payout on the first step when the block number exceeds a specified number.

```
if (block.number > 1234567) {
   payout = ...
}
```

Alternatively you can check whether `block.timestamp` exceeds a certain time.