# Can contract find the nonce of EOA while executing?

Tags: contract-development

Can contract find the nonce of EOA while executing?

Is there any way to make contract to check nonce of EOA while execution?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Contracts don't have access to the nonce data: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/2702/31933

Therefore, by extension, contracts also don't have access to the nonce data of a random EOA.

Even if you gave the address of an EOA to a contract I don't think the contract could see/know almost anything of the address, definitely not its nonce information. The contract has access to `address(EOAaddress).balance` to check the Ether balance but I think that's about it.

Nonce information is mostly client-side metadata which can only be deduced outside the blockchain by checking the last used nonce.