# When sending a transaction to a contract does the sender beforehand know the ID that will be assigned to the transaction?

Tags: transactions, contract-development

I need some ("Proof-able fair") randomization inside a contract, I was thinking of using the Transaction ID, but can the client before sending the contract know what the Transaction ID is going to be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A transaction ID is a hash of the transaction data, which is entirely determined by the user. If they wish, they can generate as many different transactions as they like until they get a hash that suits them. Further, it's not possible to access the current transaction's ID from inside Solidity.

If you need fair random numbers, see [this question](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/191/42) for advice.

Comment: Is there a English version available of that explanation?

Comment: For random numbers, see How can I securely generate a random number in my smart contract? http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/191/42

Comment: @Jeth Let me know in what way it's confusing, and I'll be happy to reword it.

Comment: It used to link to a page in mandarin? (https://github.com/randao/randao). However it's fine now.

Comment: By transaction data, do you mean the transaction data including the signature or excluding it? Does the transaction data include the nonce, gasPrice, and gasLimit?

Answer (score 2):

**When sending a transaction to a contract does the sender beforehand know the ID that will be assigned to the transaction?**

Yes.

The transaction hash is built from the transaction data. The user would be able to modify the transaction data to generate different transaction hashes.

From [core/types/transaction.go#L126-L135](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/master/core/types/transaction.go#L126-L135) :

```
// Hash hashes the RLP encoding of tx.
// It uniquely identifies the transaction.
func (tx *Transaction) Hash() common.Hash {
    if hash := tx.hash.Load(); hash != nil {
        return hash.(common.Hash)
    }
    v := rlpHash(tx)
    tx.hash.Store(v)
    return v
}
```