# How do I use the proof of work function given in here: https://www.ethereum.org/token#proof-of-work?

Tags: solidity, proof-of-work, documentation

I am creating a cryptocurrency contract, which rewards the miner a proof of work generated. To get the reward you will need to call `proofOfWork(uint nonce)`. If the nonce is correct, the miner is awarded.

I am calling this function at the end of each function, and planning to generate a random nonce which is passed as an argument for the function call. If the nonce is correct transaction is carried out and miner awarded. Else the execution is thrown.

How do I generate this random nonce? And is it the way you carry out proof of work? If not then, how do I use this function?

I am following the guide https://www.ethereum.org/token#proof-of-work .

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I securely generate a random number in my smart contract?](http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/191/how-can-i-securely-generate-a-random-number-in-my-smart-contract)

Comment: the quest for a secure source of randomness has not yet come to a happy end, Ethereum is deterministic and transparent...

Comment: Sorry, I didn't meant that in the question. I get it now - the question was a little misleading, please check the edits. Thanks for notifying.

Answer (score 2):

The idea of the nounce is that you as a miner try to guess the correct number and therefore *you can include any value you like*.
There is no way of guessing the right nounce, and the *work* the miner has to do is that of guessing the right *nounce*. It's like a lottery. You include a random parameter in your transaction and try to win the mining fee.

Comment: Then how do I implement the function in the link?

Comment: you should not call this function at the end of every function. It was intended to be externally called by your "miners"

Comment: By doing this miners will be awarded for the 'mining' which gives no advantage to my contract. Why would I need such a function? If I would have wanted to give it for free, I could just program a simple transfer function. Why the 'guide' wants to waste the computation power of miner?

Comment: you want to distribute your coins in a random way, with a simple transfer function, first comes is first served and the entire token economy will tank.

Comment: Okay. How do I call the function from miner side such that the mining starts?

Comment: it is just a normal transaction, with Mist you call a the function on the contract or you write a script in web3js for it