# Has random number generation in blockchain been solved?

Tags: blockchain, randomness

I've compared the 2 versions of the Ethereum wiki page about the hard problems of cryptoeconomics:

- https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/HPOC_2015
- https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/Problems

and found that the version from 2015 has a section titled Random Number Generation:

> The open-ended challenge is to come up with a mechanism inside of a cryptoeconomic context which provides random numbers as output with **maximally relaxed security assumptions and maximal robustness and resilience to attackers - ideally, a mechanism with the same properties as proof of work but without (or with only a negligible fraction of) its cost**.

It also mentions the "N-of-N commit-reveal, as exemplified in Tomlion's RANDAO protocol" and its limitations.

This section is missing in the latest revision of the document. Does it mean that random number generation has been solved?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I securely generate a random number in my smart contract?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/191/how-can-i-securely-generate-a-random-number-in-my-smart-contract)

Comment: Nice observation but I doubt it's been solved, haven't at least seen anything like that anywhere. Who knows why the section has been removed in the newer version....

Comment: @LauriPeltonen I think there are 3 options here: (1) it's been solved, (2) someone proved that it's unsolvable, (3) they forgot to include this section in newest revision.

Comment: Well the actual question isn't "is it solved or not", but more like "how good random numbers can we get without paying big". That ratio (randomness vs efficiency) is probably improving all the time - maybe it has improved enough that it's not considered as such a problem anymore?

Comment: @LauriPeltonen Possible. The RANDAO solution is not good enough I suspect otherwise the problem wouldn't be stated (as RANDAO itself is mentioned in that page). Do you know of anything better than RANDAO?

Comment: No, I really aren't an expert on that. Just try to stay up to date on stuff like this, without really understanding the difficult stuff.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it has been solved by [Chainlink VRF](https://blog.chain.link/random-number-generation-solidity/).

Getting a random number in a determanistic system is difficult, so we need to look outside the blockchain to get the random number. The question then, would be "is this number truly random?"

The Chainlink VRF has on-chain contracts that check to see if numbers are truly randomized, and can be easily generated.

```
pragma solidity 0.6.6;

import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.6/VRFConsumerBase.sol";

contract RandomNumberConsumer is VRFConsumerBase {
    
    bytes32 internal keyHash;
    uint256 internal fee;
    
    uint256 public randomResult;
    
    /**
     * Constructor inherits VRFConsumerBase
     * 
     * Network: Kovan
     * Chainlink VRF Coordinator address: 0xdD3782915140c8f3b190B5D67eAc6dc5760C46E9
     * LINK token address:                0xa36085F69e2889c224210F603D836748e7dC0088
     * Key Hash: 0x6c3699283bda56ad74f6b855546325b68d482e983852a7a82979cc4807b641f4
     */
    constructor() 
        VRFConsumerBase(
            0xdD3782915140c8f3b190B5D67eAc6dc5760C46E9, // VRF Coordinator
            0xa36085F69e2889c224210F603D836748e7dC0088  // LINK Token
        ) public
    {
        keyHash = 0x6c3699283bda56ad74f6b855546325b68d482e983852a7a82979cc4807b641f4;
        fee = 0.1 * 10 ** 18; // 0.1 LINK
    }
    
    /** 
     * Requests randomness from a user-provided seed
     */
    function getRandomNumber(uint256 userProvidedSeed) public returns (bytes32 requestId) {
        require(LINK.balanceOf(address(this)) >= fee, "Not enough LINK - fill contract with faucet");
        return requestRandomness(keyHash, fee, userProvidedSeed);
    }

    /**
     * Callback function used by VRF Coordinator
     */
    function fulfillRandomness(bytes32 requestId, uint256 randomness) internal override {
        randomResult = randomness;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a very good [article](https://blog.positive.com/predicting-random-numbers-in-ethereum-smart-contracts-e5358c6b8620) on Random Number Generators (PRNG) in Ethereum Smart Contracts.

There are several implementations of pseudo PRNG that use elements like `block.blockhash(block.number)` like the one done by [axiomzen](https://github.com/axiomzen/eth-random/):

```
function random(uint64 upper) public returns (uint64 randomNumber) {
  _seed = uint64(sha3(sha3(block.blockhash(block.number), _seed), now));
  return _seed % upper;
}
```

But these solutions are prone to predictability if given enough effort by an attacker. Here's an example of a [Ethereum Roulette](http://martin.swende.se/blog/Breaking_the_house.html) using this method, and how some one beat the house.

Currently the best approach is to use an external Oracle such as [oraclize](https://docs.oraclize.it/#security-deepdive-advanced-datasources-random-data-source).

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Have you seen examples of block.blockhash anywhere? I thought `block.blockhash(block.number)` will always return 0 because it can't return current block has.

Comment: Found the answer in the article that you linked

Comment: It's too broad to say "currently the best approach is to use an external oracle", although that's sometimes the right solution. It depends on the situation - for example, when all the parties to the contract are online at the same time you can use a commit-and-reveal process, which avoids adding a trusted-third-party security hole. See this answer for more on the subject: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/191/how-can-i-securely-generate-a-random-number-in-my-smart-contract

Comment: The main issue with oraclize is that is not trustless, and can be subject to certain race attacks, ie if somebody "see" the oraclize transaction before it is mined it may give an advantage.

Comment: Using an oracle such as oraclize introduces a trusted third party into the picture. To quote the oraclize documentation that you linked, the randomness comes from a "secure hardware environment provided by a Ledger Nano S." As such, there are two additional security assumptions. First, that the company producing Ledger is not acting maliciously. And second, that the secure hardware enclave works as intended. Both of these are very far from what is generally desired in decentralized blockchain settings.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest "majority vote Oracle" solves the issue. Here is an implementation in a Solidity smart contract, using one-cpu-one-vote to allocate votes.

```
contract RandomNumberOracle {
    
    uint constant period;

    function t() public view returns (uint) { return (block.number / period) * period; }

    uint nonce;

    mapping (uint => bytes32[]) blockhashes;

    mapping (uint => mapping (uint => uint)) points;

    mapping (uint => uint[]) leaderboard;
    mapping (uint => mapping (uint => uint)) leaderboardIndex;
    mapping (uint => mapping (uint => uint)) upperBound;
    mapping (uint => mapping (uint => uint)) lowerBound;

    function getRandomNumber() public view returns (uint) { return uint(blockhashes[t()-period*2][leaderboard[t()-period][0]]); }

    function vote(uint _id) public {
        require(msg.sender == block.coinbase && nonce != block.number);
        nonce = block.number;
        blockhashes[t()].push(blockhash(block.number - 1));

        if(blockhashes[t()-period].length == 0) return;

        require(_id < blockhashes[t()-period].length);

        if(points[t()][_id] == 0) {
            leaderboardIndex[t()][_id] = leaderboard[t()].length;
            if(upperBound[t()][1] == 0) upperBound[t()][1] = leaderboard[t()].length; 
            leaderboard[t()].push(_id);
        }
        else {
            uint index = leaderboardIndex[t()][_id];
            uint nextBucket = upperBound[t()][points[t()][_id]];
            if(nextBucket != index) (leaderboard[t()][nextBucket], leaderboard[t()][index]) = (leaderboard[t()][index], leaderboard[t()][nextBucket]);
            if(lowerBound[t()][points[t()][_id]] == nextBucket) { 
                lowerBound[t()][points[t()][_id]] = 0; 
                upperBound[t()][points[t()][_id]] = 0; 
            }
            else upperBound[t()][points[t()][_id]]--;

            if(upperBound[t()][points[t()][_id]+1] == 0) upperBound[t()][points[t()][_id]+1] = nextBucket;
            lowerBound[t()][points[t()][_id]+1] = nextBucket;
        }
        points[t()][_id]++;
    }
}
```