# PoA (like rinkeby) safer to generate random number (RNG) this function than POW/POS?

Tags: poa, randomness

[How can I securely generate a random number in my smart contract?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/191/how-can-i-securely-generate-a-random-number-in-my-smart-contract)

I heard that a block of random function results can be dropped by a malicious miner. Can POA prevent this?

Comment: please answer this question.