# How can I securely generate a random number in my smart contract at POA?

Tags: randomness

I heard that a block of random function results can be dropped by a malicious miner.

Can POA prevent this?

[How can I securely generate a random number in my smart contract?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/191/how-can-i-securely-generate-a-random-number-in-my-smart-contract)

Comment: Previous question https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/56628/poa-like-rinkeby-safer-to-generate-random-number-rng-this-function-than-pow. I do not think a PoA is more secure to generate random numbers. Operators have the responsibility to run the network but they are not punished for bad behavior. They might be excluded but it is not part of the protocol rules.