# i want get random number between 100-999, as follows

Tags: solidity, remix, randomness

```
function random() internal returns (uint) {
    uint random = uint(keccak256(now, msg.sender, nonce)) % 1000;
    nonce++;
    return random;
}
```

In this way, you can generate random numbers, but there will be less than 100, how to solve, thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you want is a random number within a range of 900 options.

So do this:

```
function random() internal returns (uint) {
    uint randomnumber = uint(keccak256(abi.encodePacked(now, msg.sender, nonce))) % 900;
    randomnumber = randomnumber + 100;
    nonce++;
    return randomnumber;
}
```

Basically you get a number from 0 - 899, and then add 100 to match your offset.

Comment: cool!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: BTW, notice how I changed the name of your `randomnumber` variable. You will want to keep it different from your function name. Additionally, you should use `abi.encodePacked()` before hashing the 3 values, as I have demonstrated above.

Comment: why need "you should use abi.encodePacked() before hashing the 3 values"?

Comment: You can take a look here for some details: [Deprecate variable argument mode of keccak256/sha256](https://github.com/ethereum/solidity/issues/3955). Ultimately, it is best practice to do it this way.

Comment: Be careful. That random number is 100% predictable so not suitable for a game of chance or any situation in which a participant is presumed to not be able to guess it.

Comment: @ShawnTabrizi i send email to you, pls check it.

Comment: @RobHitchens I am searching all over. Any suggestions on generating random numbers which can bot be guessed in advance?   PS: I read pretty much everything in google. Still not found satisfactory answers. And we do not want to use oracle or external sources!!  Thanks in advance for your time :)

Comment: Consider a commit/reveal pattern and add more entropy after commit and before reveal. Use extreme caution and get your code checked by multiple qualified parties.

Comment: Take a look at the Chainlink VRF, otherwise you can be attacked by miners.

Answer (score 10):

Since you're using the blockhash as your random number seed, this is actually a pseudo-random implementation. See [this post](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/191/how-can-i-securely-generate-a-random-number-in-my-smart-contract/83616#83616) for more information. To do this correctly, you'd want a decentralized oracle with provably random verification. A [Chainlink VRF](https://docs.chain.link/docs/chainlink-vrf) is your answer.

Here is a kovan implementation of your request, you can [deploy it to remix with this link](https://remix.ethereum.org/#version=soljson-v0.6.6+commit.6c089d02.js&optimize=false&evmVersion=null&gist=536123b71478ad4442cfc4278e8de577). You can look at the [Chainlink docs](https://docs.chain.link/docs/chainlink-vrf) to run an [example walkthrough](https://docs.chain.link/docs/example-walkthrough) to learn how to make Chainlink requests.

```
pragma solidity 0.6.6;

import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.6/VRFConsumerBase.sol";

contract RandomNumberConsumer is VRFConsumerBase {
    
    bytes32 internal keyHash;
    uint256 internal fee;
    
    uint256 public randomResult;
    
    /**
     * Constructor inherits VRFConsumerBase
     * 
     * Network: Kovan
     * Chainlink VRF Coordinator address: 0xdD3782915140c8f3b190B5D67eAc6dc5760C46E9
     * LINK token address:                0xa36085F69e2889c224210F603D836748e7dC0088
     * Key Hash: 0x6c3699283bda56ad74f6b855546325b68d482e983852a7a82979cc4807b641f4
     */
    constructor() 
        VRFConsumerBase(
            0xdD3782915140c8f3b190B5D67eAc6dc5760C46E9, // VRF Coordinator
            0xa36085F69e2889c224210F603D836748e7dC0088  // LINK Token
        ) public
    {
        keyHash = 0x6c3699283bda56ad74f6b855546325b68d482e983852a7a82979cc4807b641f4;
        fee = 0.1 * 10 ** 18; // 0.1 LINK
    }
    
    /** 
     * Requests randomness from a user-provided seed
     */
function getRandomNumber() public returns (bytes32 requestId) {
        require(LINK.balanceOf(address(this)) >= fee, "Not enough LINK - fill contract with faucet");
        return requestRandomness(keyHash, fee);
    }

    /**
     * Callback function used by VRF Coordinator
     */
    function fulfillRandomness(bytes32 requestId, uint256 randomness) internal override {
        randomResult = randomness;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Between min and max:

```
randomness % (max - min + 1) + min
```

Between 1 and max:

```
randomness % max + 1
```

Where randomness is uint obtained from Chainlink VRF or from any other source

Answer (score 0):

I used @Shawn Tabrizi Method

```
 function random(uint maxNumber,uint minNumber) public view returns (uint amount) {
     amount = uint(keccak256(abi.encodePacked(block.timestamp, msg.sender, block.number))) % (maxNumber-minNumber);
     amount = amount + minNumber;
     return amount;
}
```