# String of random characters

Tags: solidity, randomness

I understood that solidity can only generate pseudo-random numbers. Although, is there any way of generating a, let's say 10 character, random string?

Comment: Do you mean a truly random string? If that were possible there would be a trivial reduction to random numbers

Comment: no. I mean, a pseudo-random string.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want pseudo-random, and you aren't concerned about malicious actors gaming/breaking your system... then most people seem to take one of these approaches:

### 1) Using a hash of various block information

**Edit: I'M NOT ENDORSING THIS. YOU WILL BE GAMED.**

For example:

```
function genRandom() private view returns (uint) {
    uint rand = uint(keccak256(block.blockhash(block.number-1)));
    return uint(rand % (10 ** 20));
}
```

> source:
>   https://gist.github.com/austintgriffith/de01418675238d5292fcc7fe0de5586c#file-etherbots

[Ethernaut level 3](https://ethernaut.zeppelin.solutions/level/0xd340de695bbc39e72df800dfde78a20d2ed94035) shows just how easy this is to exploit...

### 2) Using a trusted oracle to source a random number for your contract.

Each approach has limitations and constraints already documented extensively.

Context:
[How can I securely generate a random number in my smart contract?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/191/how-can-i-securely-generate-a-random-number-in-my-smart-contract)