# Proof that a variable is truly random

Tags: blockchain, random

I have thinking of the wonder that an application could offer if it could prove that some of its data are truly random and so not controlled.

Can the ethereum blockchain offer such a service and how would it happen, can I for example display a number on my website linked with an hash linked to a smart contract that executed a random number ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I securely generate a random number in my smart contract?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/191/how-can-i-securely-generate-a-random-number-in-my-smart-contract)

I doubt that you mean true randomness based on physical phenomena: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_number_generation#%22True%22_vs._pseudo-random_numbers

Answer (score 1):

[image: I just wanted to make this answer to paste this Dilbert]

There are randomness oracles like [Chainlink VRF](https://blog.chain.link/verifiable-random-functions-vrf-random-number-generation-rng-feature/) available nowadays.