# Can you get an array of random numbers?

Tags: solidity, oracles, random

The question says it all. Can I get an array of random numbers in solidity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Getting a random number in solidity is tricky by itself because blockchains are deterministic. You'll want to reach outside the blockchain, but [only with services that can prove their numbers are random](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/83616/57451). To do this, you'd want to use [Chainlink VRF](https://docs.chain.link/docs/chainlink-vrf/) and return a whole array.

You can then create an `expand` function, that is a whole of array of random numbers based on the seed random number.

```js
function expand(uint256 randomValue, uint256 n) public pure returns (uint256[] memory expandedValues) {
    expandedValues = new uint256[](n);
    for (uint256 i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        expandedValues[i] = uint256(keccak256(abi.encode(randomValue, i)));
    }
    return expandedValues;
}
```

For context, here is what a full contract on the kovan testnet would look like:

```js
pragma solidity 0.6.6;

import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.6/VRFConsumerBase.sol";

/**
 * THIS IS AN EXAMPLE CONTRACT WHICH USES HARDCODED VALUES FOR CLARITY.
 * PLEASE DO NOT USE THIS CODE IN PRODUCTION.
 */
contract RandomNumberConsumer is VRFConsumerBase {
    
    bytes32 internal keyHash;
    uint256 internal fee;
    
    uint256 public randomResult;
    
    /**
     * Constructor inherits VRFConsumerBase
     * 
     * Network: Kovan
     * Chainlink VRF Coordinator address: 0xdD3782915140c8f3b190B5D67eAc6dc5760C46E9
     * LINK token address:                0xa36085F69e2889c224210F603D836748e7dC0088
     * Key Hash: 0x6c3699283bda56ad74f6b855546325b68d482e983852a7a82979cc4807b641f4
     */
    constructor() 
        VRFConsumerBase(
            0xdD3782915140c8f3b190B5D67eAc6dc5760C46E9, // VRF Coordinator
            0xa36085F69e2889c224210F603D836748e7dC0088  // LINK Token
        ) public
    {
        keyHash = 0x6c3699283bda56ad74f6b855546325b68d482e983852a7a82979cc4807b641f4;
        fee = 0.1 * 10 ** 18; // 0.1 LINK (Varies by network)
    }
    
    /** 
     * Requests randomness 
     */
    function getRandomNumber() public returns (bytes32 requestId) {
        require(LINK.balanceOf(address(this)) >= fee, "Not enough LINK - fill contract with faucet");
        return requestRandomness(keyHash, fee);
    }

    /**
     * Callback function used by VRF Coordinator
     */
    function fulfillRandomness(bytes32 requestId, uint256 randomness) internal override {
        randomResult = randomness;
    }

    // function withdrawLink() external {} - Implement a withdraw function to avoid locking your LINK in the contract

function expand(uint256 randomValue, uint256 n) public pure returns (uint256[] memory expandedValues) {
    expandedValues = new uint256[](n);
    for (uint256 i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        expandedValues[i] = uint256(keccak256(abi.encode(randomValue, i)));
    }
    return expandedValues;
}
}
```

Comment: For context,  I work on the chainlink protocol.

Comment: I dont see how you are using expand() to get the array full of random numbers. I am confused as to where to call this function from so I can use it.

Comment: Oh! You'd call the `expand` method separately after requesting the random number

Comment: so using your example would it be something like: expand(randomness, 9); called from within the fulfillRandomness callback to get the array of random numbers I need? could you provide an example please? im assuming the result of that call is an array of course.

Comment: You got it! I'm not sure what I'd offer as an example, you said exactly what you should do. Call `expand(randomness, 9)`

Comment: my god, you are a Jedi. I got it to work perfectly thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I used for my lottery smart contract to pick a random winner

```
    contract Lottery {
    
...
    
        address[] public players;
    
...
    
    function random() private view returns (uint256){
            return uint(keccak256(block.difficulty, now, players));
        }
    
    ...
    
     function pickWinner() public restricted {
    ...
    
           uint256 index = random() % players.length;
           players[index].transfer(this.balance);
        
        ...
    }
```

You can use sha3 as well

Comment: This is pseudo-random, not actually random. The `block.difficulty` can be manipulated.

Comment: @PatrickCollins thank you for your reply. I am pretty new in the solidity world and this was the single method that I used for "random" things.

I will try your method as well!