# Is there an alternative to Chainlink to get a random number in a solidity contract?

Tags: solidity, chainlink, randomness, vrf, random

I'm trying to create an NFT that selects at random between 3 json metadata files. The only way I know of to do this is to use Chainlink. I've seen one tutorial that implements `"@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.6/VRFConsumerBase.sol"`. Is there some other protocol that does this? I need to generate a random number between and including 1 and 3. Or just any random number that I can modulo to get a number between and including 1 and 3. I like Chainlink, I just want to know if there are other options. Maybe a different oracle project like Kylin, Band Protocol, or API3?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I securely generate a random number in my smart contract?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/191/how-can-i-securely-generate-a-random-number-in-my-smart-contract)

Comment: That's close but not quite my question. Most of the answers here are Chainlink. There are some people suggesting RANDAO which is an option but I'm exclusively looking for Chainlink alternatives.